# Regex for returning several patterns within one string

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to extract names from the text below, i.e., any string occurrences that appear between "applicant(s).: " and the following ",Please". Is this possible?

`Please enter the name of your school.: Test Primary School,Please enter the name(s) of your applicant(s).: Sandra McTest,Please enter the name of your school.: Test Primary School,Please enter the name(s) of your applicant(s).: Grace Test, Brad Test, Lovelace Test,Please enter the name of your school.: Test Primary School,`

I'd really appreciate some help as I'm just getting started with regex. Thanks heaps in advance.

Comment: It did! Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`look-arounds`](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind)

`/(?<=applicant\(s\)\.:).*?(?=Please|$)/gm`

It captures everyting between `applicant(s).:` string and `Please` string or `end of line`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TX5xMg/1)